# Terminal sudo apt-get update

Tags: pantheon-terminal, sudo

I seem to be having a problem when I use `sudo apt-get update` & `sudo apt-get upgrade`.
(Freya 32bits)
I get this:- photos enclosed.[image: Terminal[![Terminal2]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HFPex.png)

Comment: You've a problem on your network configuration. It's not a problem with update-upgrqde. All your repositories try to connect to a local IP. Try to configure it.

Comment: Cheers Mr. But when I open a browser it does give me the possibility to serf and I don't seem to have any problems with it.

Answer (score 1):

You have misconfigured your proxy.

Go to Configuration -> Network -> Proxy settings.  Change the actual value ( Automatic or 192.168.1.2) to "Direct connection to Internet"

Save new settings and restart network from terminal with the command :

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

Try apt-get update again

Answer (score -1):

follow the steps below to fix it :-

Open /etc/apt/sources.list file.

Check the word after http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ in the sources.list file, 
let the word be xyz ..
Go to the address http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ and then click on dists.

Now check whether xyz is present at this path. If it is not present, then replace xyz with the element which is present in 'dists' such as:- saucy, lucid, trusty etc.Now run

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Source : [WebCheerz.com](http://WebCheerz.com)

Comment: That's a proxy/DNS misconfiguration.

Comment: Cheers people I did what you said & every thing functions as before. Have a gôôd day.